# Changing a pixel based on the results of a comparison using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to compare two images that appear to be the same but the RGB average differs for each.

I have created a new blank image and I will plot a coloured pixel if the two images match in that location and if they don't match then it will plot a different colour pixel hopefully highlighting the pixel locations of the altered pixels.

```
diff_img = Image.new('RGB', (width,height), "black")
map_diff = diff_img.load()
Good_count = 0

for i in range(open_img1.size[0]):
    for j in range(open_img1.size[1]):
        if File1[i] == File2[i] and File2[j] == File2[j]:
            Good_count += 1
        else:
            map_diff[i,j] = (255, 255, 255) # set the colour accordingly

diff_img.show()
```

This currently gives me just a black image so no pixels have been altered on the new image I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as from what I can see if the row and column of the two files don't match it will change the pixel to a white one?

Comment: I mean you start with a black image and actually never change anything about it so you end up with a black image. By which I mean you manipulate map_diff but plot diff_img

Comment: @haxor789 I have changed that but i get the same error and as per the documentation I was looking at they used the pixel map to change the pixels and it was applied to the actual picture

Comment: What kind of "error"? Like do you get an error message or is it just still black? Also is it all black or mostly black?

Comment: It is still all black that is what I mean by error my fault!

Comment: You need to provide an [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean PIL works with numpy arrays or at least can be easily converted to them, so I'd just work with that.

```
from PIL import Image    
img = np.array(Image.open(File1)) 
img2 = np.array(Image.open(File2))
img3 = img == img2
Image.fromarray(img3).save("test.png")
```

This should already do it.

Comment: I have tried this way but when I did it it just returned a bunch of RGB values in the terminal... no file was created

Comment: You could convert them to grayscale with img = img.convert("L") or you could compare each of the 3 RGB layers separately in numpy and then just compare the resulting masks with the and operator.